# Fitting multiplicative model in a Frequentist way in R

Tags: r, regression-coefficients

Say, I have sensory panel data for 30 products, which are scored by 11 panelist in 2 replicates for different traits. To fit this data,I am using model of the form:

$y_{ijr} = \alpha_j + \beta_j\cdot\theta_i + error_{ijr}$

i= panelists, j= products, r= replicates

In this model, I am considering multiplicative interaction for beta_j(for panelists) and theta_j(for products). Error term is heterogeneous and panelist-dependent. I am trying to fit this model in R, so I can get separate coefficients for alpha_j, beta_j, theta_i and error_ijr. 
Does anyone can suggest me is it possible to fit this model in frequentist way and what would be appropriate R package or function to do these.

Comment: An interaction doesn't mean to multiply parameters, it's about multiplying regressors. Thus, the model looks a bit strange. Repeated measures anova with heterogeneous variances can be modelled in R e.g. using package 'nlme'.